# GNU Make, value of `$<` from multiple prerequisite lines

Tags: variables, makefile, prerequisites

In a situation like this:

```
sample.o: sample.hpp
%.o: %.cpp
     $(CXX) -o $@ -c $<

sample.o: utility.hpp
```

when compiling sample.o, what is the first prerequisite (value of `$<`)? `sample.hpp`? `sample.cpp`? ... `utility.hpp`? `sample.hpp` is the first prerequisite found by make. `sample.cpp` is the first requisite of the rule that contains the recipe, which is what makes most sense. `utility.hpp` makes no sense to be used as a first prerequisite but I put it for completness.

What if?

```
sample.o: sample.hpp utility.hpp
# implicit rule %.o: %.cpp
```

What if?

```
%.o: %.cpp # Removal of implicit rule/recipe.
sample.o: sample.hpp
%.o: %.cpp %.d
     $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Here the first prerequisite could be `sample.cpp` from the first line, or `sample.hpp` since `%.o: %.cpp` is overriden by `%.o: %.cpp %.d` and `sample.hpp` is then the new first prerequisite; or `sample.cpp` again because it's the first prerequisite of the rule containing the recipe.

What if?

```
sample.o: sample.hpp
%.o: %.cpp
sample.o: utility.hpp
%.o: %.cpp %.d
     $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Same argument, it could be `sample.hpp` or `sample.cpp` for the fourth line.

In short, what is the criteria or algorithm used by GNU Make to fill `$<`?

Answer (score 0):

The info file says (my emphasis):

> ### `$<`
>
> The name of the first prerequisite.  **If the target got its recipe
> from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by
> the implicit rule**.

This confirms the hypothesis you say "makes most sense".

Comment: Yeah but I have also put samples without implicit rules and with explicit removal of implicit rules and so on.

Comment: Well, we can easily experiment using `echo '$<'` to get a full answer for those cases.

Comment: Peregring-lk I don't understand the distinctions you're trying to make here.  There are only implicit and explicit rules, that's all.  If there's an explicit rule it's used.  If not and there's an implicit rule it's used.  If neither exists, make will fail with "no rule to build target".  So asking what happens "without implicit rules" doesn't make sense.